# Displaying full table row content on mouseclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have a table in my webpage using data tables.(https://datatables.net/). I have very long sentences in each cell of the column. I need a way such that only on mouseover or mouseclick the entire data in the cell must be displayed.

please tell me how I can go about doing this.

P.S I'm very new to php javascript.

This is the code I have sourced.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" /> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Something like [this](https://datatables.net/beta/1.9/examples/advanced_init/events_post_init.html)? May need minor changes to adapt to your version of datatables

Comment: Also, take a look at `responsive` plugin of datatables. It implements a good example for bootstrap modals. See docs and demo [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html)

Answer (score 0):

This has not much to do with PHP, more CSS / Javascript. Maybe datatables has an option for this, not found yet. But what you could do:

1. In PHP, where you build the content of the cells, just echo the first 5 words. The rest of the words you echo between a `<span>` tag with a class `hidden toggle`.
2. In CSS make a class `.hidden{display:none;}`
3. Make a Javascript function that is triggered by the `toggle` class and it should add or remove the class `hidden`. This will show or hide the full sentence.

In jQuery toggling of a class is very simple, also triggering a function on a click.

Good luck!

Comment: Posted comments on the question with relevant `datatables` specific suggestions. You are free to include them in your answer.